# Is my proof ok? $O(f(n)g(n))=f(n)O(g(n)).$ (on p.108 in "The Art of Computer Programming Volume 1" by Donald E. Knuth)

Tags: solution-verification, asymptotics

I am reading "The Art of Computer Programming Volume 1" by Donald E. Knuth.

The following formula is on p.108:

> $O(f(n)g(n))=f(n)O(g(n))\tag{10}\label{10}.$

I proved $\eqref{10}$ holds, but I am not familiar with $O$ notation.
Is my proof ok or not?
If my proof is not ok, please tell me a standard proof.
If my proof is ok but my proof is not standard, please tell me a standard proof.

> Let $h(n)\in O(f(n)g(n))$.
> There exist positive constants $M$ and $n_0$ such that $|h(n)|\leq M|f(n)g(n)|$ for all integers $n\geq n_0$.
> Let $h_2(n) :=
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{h(n)}{f(n)},  & \text{if $f(n)\neq 0$} \\
> 0. & \text{if $f(n)=0$}
> \end{cases}
> $
> Note that $h(n)=0$ if $n\geq n_0$ and $f(n)=0$.
> So, if $n\geq n_0$, then $h(n)=f(n)h_2(n)$.
> If $f(n)=0$ and $n\geq n_0$, then $|h_2(n)|=0\leq M|g(n)|$.
> If $f(n)\neq 0$ and $n\geq n_0$, then $|h(n)|\leq M|f(n)g(n)|$.
> So, if $f(n)\neq 0$ and $n\geq n_0$, then $|h_2(n)|=|\frac{h(n)}{f(n)}|\leq M|g(n)|$.
> So, $h_2(n)\in O(g(n)).$
> So, $h(n)\in f(n)O(g(n)).$
> Therefore, $O(f(n)g(n))\subset f(n)O(g(n))$.
> This means $O(f(n)g(n))=f(n)O(g(n))$ by convention.